# MongoDB query by datetime field 1h interval

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo-3.x

I've been trying to extract one record each 1 hour from a collection with 1 record each 10 seconds on the **datetime** (Date). The document is like this:

```
datetime: 2021-11-26T15:08:20.000+00:00
owner_id: "INTERNAL"
motor_id: 24
```

The **datetime** document field is Date() type.

On this collection I've **1 record each 10 seconds on datetime field** (several days), but I would like to extract just one record each **1 hour datetime interval**. How could I archive this?

Thanks in advance for any tip, help or direction to the right documentation.

I was trying to follow this: https://mongoing.com/docs/reference/operator/aggregation/filter.html with no success. Not sure how to increment the hour.

EDIT: Some more information about the collection:

collection1 with 26.303 records like this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "644b34a3756b9c1dc169e20d"
  },
  "datetime": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1637939300000"
    }
  },
  "customer_id": "INTERNAL",
  "owner_id": "INTERNAL",
  "GMHP": -0.54,
  "AMHP": 198.19,
  "OMHP": 428.883544921875,
  "AROP": 148.57066345214844,
  "OROP": 102.5451889038086
}
```

Each document has a 10 seconds interval stored in datetime field. I've plans to change those documents to time-series in the future.
My goal is to select the documents on each hour, e.g:

1st document datetime: 2021-11-26T**15:08:20**.000+00:00
2nd document datetime: 2021-11-26T**15:09:20**.000+00:00
and so on...

I could safely ignore all fields between T15:**08:30** to T15:**09:10**.

Comment: Please provide some sample input data

Comment: What do you mean by "one record"? Which one do you like to get? The middle one or the first one or the last one, etc.

Comment: What kind of collection is this? Presumably time-series?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I've updated the question with the complete document structure. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @MattKneiser They should be time-series but this couldn't be archived yet. We have only one field to store the event datetime. The default granularity is 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to simply use `$dateToParts`. If you have a document for each 10 seconds, the `$match` step will return the first document for each hour:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$set: {
      datetimeParts: {
        $dateToParts: {
          date: "$datetime"
        }
      }
  }},
  {$match: {
      "datetimeParts.minute": 0,
      "datetimeParts.second": {$lt: 10}
  }},
  {$unset: "datetimeParts"}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bWdvDhcr-c1)

Comment: It worked very well for MongoDB. Thanks for your help, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some struggle I was trying to make the query sent by nimrod serok to work both on Mongo and DocumentDB. Then I realized how limited problematic is DocumentDB when using PyMongo or vanilla MongoDB driver.

The `$set` is not supported on DocumentDB, so I had to replace it by `$addFields`. After that I realized `dateToParts` is also not supported because this function expects a string format and I had a Date() type.

If by any chance anyone wants to achieve similar results on DocumentDB here is a workaround. Probably there are better solutions for that, however it worked for me with the same results as Mongo query.

(Im using PyMongo)

the `entry_date` determines the first datetime from the collection, it's optional. You can replace the `minute` and `second` variables to fit your range needs.

I hope it can help the DocumentDB users as well.

```
entry_date = db.collection.find_one(filter=filtering, sort=[('datetime', 1)])
    entry_date = entry_date['datetime']
    minute = entry_date.minute
    second = entry_date.second
    report = db.collection.aggregate([
        {
            "$addFields": {
                "hour": {"$hour": "$datetime"},
                "minute": {"$minute": "$datetime"},
                "second": {"$second": "$datetime"},
                "year": {"$year": "$datetime"},
                "month": {"$month": "$datetime"},
                "day": {"$dayOfMonth": "$datetime"}
            }
        },
        {
            "$match": {
                "minute": minute,
                "second": second
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 0,
                "datetime": 1,
                "hour": 1,
                "minute": 1,
                "second": 1,
                "year": 1,
                "month": 1,
                "day": 1
            }
        }
    ])
```